# Sharing configuration in Leiningen project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project that uses the [lein-beanstalk](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-beanstalk) Leiningen plugin to deploy my app to Amazon [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

My Elastic Beanstalk application has multiple environments (e.g. development, staging, production, etc.), each with different configuration. The configuration is managed by Elastic Beanstalk environment properties, which are set in the JVM as system properties. lein-beanstalk manages these properties with the following entry in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject eb-app "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :aws {:beanstalk {:environments [{:name "staging"
                                    :env {"com.example.fooLimit" "3"
                                          "com.example.barName" "BAR"}}
                                   {:name "production"
                                    :env {"com.example.fooLimit" "27"
                                          "com.example.barName" "BAR"}}]}})
```

In this example, only `com.example.fooLimit` varies between my environments, so I'd like to use a var to hold the shared conf. Since `defproject` is a macro that quotes everything, I can accomplish what I want with a syntax unquote:

```
(def cfg {"com.example.barName" "BAR"})

(defproject eb-app "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :aws {:environments [{:name "staging"
                        :env ~(merge cfg {"com.example.fooLimit" "3"}})
                       {:name "production"
                        :env ~(merge cfg {"com.example.fooLimit" "27"}})}]}})
```

My question is whether this is common in Clojure projects, or if there is a more idiomatic or industry-standard way (among Clojure programmers) to DRY up `project.clj`?

Comment: I didn't see it before, but it's a nice idea... Just to see where the config.cfg file is managed in Leiningen to be sure there is no side effect creating a global definition.